# Uploading ios build .dSYM files in Fabric takes long time

Tags: ios, xcode, google-fabric, dsym

When I upload .dSYM files in Fabric it takes long time! Any Suggestions? 
and why these files not included in the build?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your internet is slow. dSYM files can be huge. As long as they're uploaded, you can close the Fabric page and wait for it to process. As for uploading them, there's not much anyone can do except get you faster Wi-Fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you permanently, after this you do not need to upload dSYM file separately.

Just go to Build Settings and then turn on these parameters:

```
Debug: DWARF with dSYM File
Release: DWARF with dSYM File
Enable Bitcode: No
```

This problem basically occurs if you have not implemented fabric in the proper way.

For reference: [see this](https://medium.com/@nickmeehan/fabric-dsym-files-cc34a8290f6)

Comment: I've already used `DWARF with dSYM File` in both `Debug` & `Release` while `Enable Bitcode` was 'YES', if I set it to `No` will it solve the issue? @Sazid

Comment: In my case the problem solved after setting enable bitcode to NO @elgawady14

Comment: By doing thes chages previous dsmy missed issue not resolved but, by doing this the problem for next crash report will solved, in next reports dsmy file issue will reolved after doing these change. @elgawady14

Comment: Yes got it!, while I will lose the advantage of enabling `Bitcode`!

Comment: As per my experience, there is no impact by this on app.

Comment: Thanks bro @Sazid